# strange output with bootstrap table in while loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, while-loop

i try to make a while loop with boostrap table but it gives me a strange output

here is an image
[image]

as you see after the second loop the output is outside of my selected div.

also only the first row of the table is placed right.the rest of the rows are shown as you seen in the image

here is my code

```
 <?php
    $x= 1;
    while ( $x <= $_SESSION['noc']){
        require ('conntodb.php');
        $stmt= $conn->prepare('SELECT catname FROM food_category WHERE st_id= :st_id AND catcount= :catcount' );
        $stmt->bindParam(':st_id',$_SESSION['st_id']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':catcount', $x);
        $stmt->execute();
        $catres= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($catres as $row) {
        echo "<h3>" . $row['catname'] . "</h3>";
    }
    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>"
    ."<table class='table table-condensed'>"
    ."<thead><tr><th>Πίατο</th><th>Τιμή</th><th>Επεξεργασία</th></tr></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
 $selall1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT food_id, fname, fprice FROM food_1 WHERE st_id= :st_id AND ftype= :ftype ORDER BY food_id ASC');
    $selall1->bindParam(':st_id',$_SESSION['st_id']);
    $selall1->bindParam(':ftype',$x);
    $selall1->execute();
    $useres1 = $selall1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($useres1 as $rows) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $rows['fname'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['fprice'] . "</td>   <td><a href='pledit.php?id=" . $rows['food_id'] . "'>Επεξεργασία</a></td></tr>";
echo "</tbody>"
."</table>"
."</div>";
}
$x++;
}

?>
```

my first thought was that the div has not enough height but after i setting some height in the div i get this output:

[image]

what am i missing guys?

thanks in advance

vaggelis

Comment: check html output, it should be quite messed up, and try to put `echo "</tbody></table></div>";` outside of the loop -> what does it show then  ?

Comment: hello @OldPadawan i changed  it  and now working.thank you very much for your help! cheers

Comment: cool ! answer posted, good coding for the future... @vaggelis : please close topic then

Comment: would have been nice to validate to original, not the copy, never mind :)

Comment: @OldPadawan i didnt know that i can validate a comment.how can i do this?

Comment: my answer was/is now at the bottom :)

Comment: ok i found it and validated it. i saw only your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check html output, it should be quite messed up, and try to put

```
<?php
echo "</tbody></table></div>"; //outside of the loop
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the end of your code:

```
foreach ($useres1 as $rows) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $rows['fname'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['fprice'] . "</td>   <td><a href='pledit.php?id=" . $rows['food_id'] . "'>Επεξεργασία</a></td></tr>";
    echo "</tbody>"
        . "</table>"
        . "</div>";
}
```

to:

```
foreach ($useres1 as $rows) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $rows['fname'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['fprice'] . "</td>   <td><a href='pledit.php?id=" . $rows['food_id'] . "'>Επεξεργασία</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>"
    . "</table>"
    . "</div>";
```

Comment: -> as commented above ^^